# Colored label texts in a matplotlib stem plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I like do a stem-plit with Pythons `matplotlib` where the figure has a legend box where the labels are colored like the stems. At the moment I only get a legend where the label text is the normal black and has a short stem plot on the left. I would like it to be only the label text but that one colored like the corresponding stems (e.g. blue and green in the example below).

Note that the actual stem plot is part of a figure with multiple subplots, so I would like the solution to use the `ax` handler instead of `plt`, if possible.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = np.arange(0, 10)

x1 = np.sin(n)
x2 = np.cos(n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.stem(n, x1, 'b', markerfmt='bo', label="First")
ax.stem(n, x2, 'g', markerfmt='go', label="Second")
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

In short the legend box should only contain "First" in blue and "Second" in green without any lines or dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may loop over the legend entries to set the text color to the color of the legend handle.

```
leg = ax.legend()
for h, t in zip(leg.legendHandles, leg.get_texts()):
    t.set_color(h.get_color()[0])
```

Now unfortunately the legend handle itself consists of several artists in the case of a stem plot, such that something like `t.set_visible(False)` does not work for setting the handle invisible. Instead one would dig a little deeper in the legend to find the `DrawingArea` of the handle and set this complete area invisible.

```
for l in leg._legend_handle_box.get_children()[0].get_children():
    l.get_children()[0].set_visible(False)
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = np.arange(0, 10)

x1 = np.sin(n)
x2 = np.cos(n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.stem(n, x1, 'b', markerfmt='bo', label="First")
ax.stem(n, x2, 'g', markerfmt='go', label="Second")

leg = ax.legend()

for h, t in zip(leg.legendHandles, leg.get_texts()):
    t.set_color(h.get_color()[0])

for l in leg._legend_handle_box.get_children()[0].get_children():
    l.get_children()[0].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I also tested it with my normal line plots where ist works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`basefmt`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = np.arange(0, 10)

x1 = np.sin(n)
x2 = np.cos(n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.stem(n, x1, 'b', markerfmt='bo', basefmt=" ", label="First")
ax.stem(n, x2, 'g', markerfmt='go', basefmt=" ", label="Second")
x = np.linspace(*ax.get_xlim())
ax.plot(x, x*0, 'r-')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

This results in [image]

I now put the baseline in a hacky way into it, but it works. You can change the parts for the baseline so that it starts at 0 and ends at 9 if wanted.